# GLSL subroutine not recognized

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, lwjgl

I have recently tried subroutine feature of OpenGL 4.0 with lwjgl and I can't make it work. When querying GL_ACTIVE_SUBROUTINE_UNIFORM_LOCATIONS, I get 0, and thus subroutine uniform. When querying each routine's index, I always get -1, which tells me that they don't "exist".

Here are my shaders:
Vertex shader:

```
    #version 400

    subroutine vec4 getColor(vec4 color);

    uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
    uniform mat4 ViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 ModelMatrix;

    subroutine uniform getColor myColor;

    layout(location = 0) in vec4 inPosition;
    layout(location = 1) in vec4 inColor;

    // Smooth
    out vec4 vColor;

    subroutine (getColor) vec4 invertColor(vec4 color){
        return vec4(1.0 - color.r, 1.0 - color.g, 1.0 - color.b, color.a);}

    subroutine (getColor) vec4 realColor(vec4 color){
        return color;}

    void main(){
        gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * inPosition;
        vColor = invertColor(inColor);}
```

Fragment shader:

```
    #version 400

    // Smooth
    in vec4 vColor;

    out vec4 pixel;

    void main(){
        pixel = vColor;}
```

And here's my code:

```
    shader.useProgram();
    routineInvertColor = GL40.glGetSubroutineIndex(shader.getProgramId(), GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "invertColor");
    routineRealColor = GL40.glGetSubroutineIndex(shader.getProgramId(), GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "realColor");
    routineUniform = GL40.glGetSubroutineUniformLocation(shader.getProgramId(), GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "myColor");
    IntBuffer subroutineBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1).put(routineInvertColor);

    System.out.println(GL40.glGetProgramStagei(shader.getProgramId(), GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, GL40.GL_ACTIVE_SUBROUTINE_UNIFORM_LOCATIONS));
    System.out.println(routineInvertColor + " " + routineRealColor + " " + routineUniform);

    GL40.glUniformSubroutinesu(GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, subroutineBuffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it. I was doing something really stupid. But before that, I mixed on stackoverflow invertColor(inColor) and getColor(inColor):

What I was doing:

```
getColor(inColor);
```

What I should have been doing:

```
myColor(inColor);
```